# Why bottom navigation fragment become black in color and not working in android?

Tags: java, android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

[image]

I don't know why fragment is not working. I am creating bottom navigation. My code is here. Please solve my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/draw">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bot_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

This is the fragment part. Please solve my problem. The app is not working.
This is the fragment part. Please solve my problem. The app is not working.

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bot_nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/bot_navigation"
        />



    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay." />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the bot_navigation.xml code. Please check it also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bot_navigation"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_feed"
        android:name="com.example.reducestress.ui.feed.feed"
        android:label="@string/title_feed"
        tools:layout="@layout/feed_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_diary"
        android:name="com.example.reducestress.ui.diary.diary"
        android:label="@string/title_diary"
        tools:layout="@layout/diary_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:name="com.example.reducestress.ui.profile.profile"
        android:label="@string/title_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/profile_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Did you add the fragments you want to display to your bot_navigation? And did you setup your Navigation in the parent Activity?

Comment: i add the main fragment in contentmain.xml

Answer (score 2):

With the new JetPack Navigation, you need to add the fragments you want to show to your NavGraph. You can find your NavGraph under the `navigation` directory from the `res` directory. In your case, your NavGraph is `bot_navigation.xml`.

If you don't see the fragment you want to show, once you are inside your NavGraph, there will be this icon

[image]

Click it and you will see a list of the available fragments and activities. Just click the one you want.

If your fragments are already placed, make sure the id's match with the id's in your `bottom_navigation_menu.xml`. Also, make sure that in your host activity you are setting up the `Navigation` with the right `NavController` and with the right `BottomNavigationView`.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Then can you show a print or a gif of your app with the black screen? Can you also post the bot_navigation.xml code and also the code you are using to setup the navigation please?

Comment: 1. The app is not running when I run an emulator.

Comment: 2. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bot_navigation"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_feed"
        android:name="com.example.reducestress.ui.feed.feed"
        android:label="@string/title_feed"
        tools:layout="@layout/feed_fragment" />

Comment: <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_diary"
        android:name="com.example.reducestress.ui.diary.diary"
        android:label="@string/title_diary"
        tools:layout="@layout/diary_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:name="com.example.reducestress.ui.profile.profile"
        android:label="@string/title_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/profile_fragment" />
</navigation>

Comment: Edit your question with the code, it's impossible to debug with the code in the comments

Comment: I did it, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

try to change <fragment to <FrameLayout its work for me when i use FrameLayout
and turn black when i change it to <fragment

Comment: app:defaultNavHost="true"
app:navGraph="@navigation/bot_navigation"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot in **`navigation`**  **`app: startDestination = "@ id / navigation_feed`** instead of navigation_feed put the fragment that should be launched first and i think you should remove unusedNavigation

**The code that should look like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bot_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_feed">
...
</navigation>
```